# Percent sign in variable definition

Tags: javascript

I am looking at code that has this line:

```
var % 20 linkcount = 0;
```

What is going on here?

There are also lines like this:

```
var % 20 linkAnchor % 20 = % 20 anchorLink % 20 + % 20 "something"
```

Comment: Do you mean `%20` not `% 20` (with space)? Spaces matter. This looks like an HTML dump of some code where space has been encoded as `%20`. So you need to provide some context. So really the code originally is, `var linkcount = 0;` and `var linkAnchor = anchorLink + "something"`.

Comment: If I run your code verbatim I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator so that code is actually invalid.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco It's solved already. It's just a whitespace in unicode.

Comment: Thank you everyone, @lurker is correct. I'm not sure why the `%20` are in the code in place of white spaces. The spacing was introduced by a code indentation formatter I used to make the code readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%20 is the unicode character entity for the space (" ") character. These are usually used in URLs by browsers.